# Stripping numbers dates until first alphabet is found from string

Tags: python, strip

I am trying an efficient way to strip numbers dates or any other characters present in a string until the first alphabet is found from the end.

string - `'12.abd23yahoo 04/44 231'`
Output - `'12.abd23yahoo'`

```
line_inp = "12.abd23yahoo 04/44 231"
line_out = line_inp.rstrip('0123456789./')
```

This `rstrip()` call doesn't seem to work as expected, I get `'12.abd23yahoo 04/44 '` instead.

I am trying below and it doesn't seem to be working.

```
for fname in filenames:
with open(fname) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.rstrip('0123456789./ '))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a regular expression:

```
import re    
line_inp = "12.abd23yahoo 04/44 231"
r = re.compile('^(.*[a-zA-Z])')
m = re.match(r, line_inp)
line_out = m.group(0) # 12.abd23yahoo
```

The regular expression matches a group of arbitrary characters which end in a letter.

Comment: thank you, this reg_exp works perfectly but when I use file reader I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: m is None when the line does not match this pattern. You just need to check for that: `if m == None: continue`

Comment: @ Andreas Thank you big time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip spaces too:

```
line_out = line_inp.rstrip('0123456789./ ')
```

Demo:

```
>>> line_inp = "12.abd23yahoo 04/44 231"
>>> line_inp.rstrip('0123456789./ ')
'12.abd23yahoo'
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters. I am trying to read the line from file and output the converted text, bu somehow it's not working.

Comment: Include `\n` in the characters: `rstrip('0123456789./ \n')`

Comment: @yatri: sounds like you have newlines too then. Add `\n` to the stripped characters. Always test your input with `repr(line_inp)` to make such characters more visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the newlines and add it again before you write :

```
for fname in filenames:
     with open(fname) as infile:
        outfile.writelines(line.rstrip('0123456789./ \n') + "\n" 
                              for line in infile)
```

If the format is always the same you can just split:

```
with open(fname) as infile:
        outfile.writelines(line.split(None, 1)[0] + "\n" 
                              for line in infile)
```

Comment: Thank you @Padraic. I don't want to strip newline cause it will put all together and mess data. I want each line done separately as each line is a separate entity.

Comment: thank you. But the format is not the same it text in the line could of any length with multiple spaces and space number between them. Trying to delete only the numbers after the last alphabet. For example for this string   /sa/.0e0770h .Test Main 2nd 01/21 3.21 Output should be "/sa/.0e0770h .Test Main 2nd".

Comment: First code will work regardless, you just need to add the newline back in after stripping it off